# Purpose of *,& symbol behide datatype?

Tags: pointers, graph

I am learning to implement graph using c++. I came across to see the follow code. Could anyone explain what is the function of symbols * and & behide the data type "vertex" and "string"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct vertex {
  typedef pair<int, vertex*> ve;
  vector <ve> adj; //cost of edge, distination to vertex
  string name;
  vertex (string s) : name(s) {}
};

class gragh
{
public:
  typedef map<string, vertex *> vmap;
  vmap work;
  void addvertex (const string&);
  void addedge (const string& from, const string&, double cost);
};

void gragh::addvertex (const string &name)
{
  vmap::iterator itr = work.find(name);
  if (itr == work.end())
  {
    vertex *v;
    v = new vertex(name);
    work[name] = v;
    return;
  }
  cout << "Vertex alreay exist";
 }

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'*' means to de-reference something i.e. go to the address of some variable whose address lies in the pointer.

`int x=*p;`

This means `x` will have the value of memory address to whom `p` is pointing.

`x=&p;`

This means `x` will have the address of that memory location where `p` resides.

Comment: Thank you. How about & symbol in this line of code: void addvertex (const string&). Is it also mean de-reference something?

Comment: It means that the string this will accept will be accepted by reference, i.e. the changes made to the string will remain after function call. Please accept this answer if it solved your issue.